# Determine a percentage of an unfilled quota

Tags: divisibility, percentages, direct-sum

I am having a bit of a computer programming challenge, c#, however the actual issue I believe stems from myself not understanding the maths behing it, hence me posting here...

So my challenge.

We have a number of products that need to be sold, like this...

| PRODUCT | INSTOCK | SOLD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 100 | 50 |
| SKU2 | 200 | 30 |
| SKU3 | 300 | 75 |

I need to figure out 51% of the total unsold, which is going to be a target for a sales team.

So far I go ok thats fine I can go (INSTOCK - SOLD) gives me my unsold, add it all up and get 51%, but this is a circular solution as when more is sold it will alter this calculation forever moving and relying on itself.

So then is it as simple as suming all instock and sold and comparing so...

SUM OF SOLD / SUM of INSTOCK * 100 and checking if this is 51%, this seems to simple to me and overly favouritable to the sales team. The challenge here is to get 51% of the total unsold, so the difference between instock and sold.

My question is then what is best math solution to figure out this challenge, is there a simple technique I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed, 51% of the total unsold will always depend on the number of sold items (as well as those in stock). In other words, to recover total unsold, you need both values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. With these data, the target is to sell (essentially) half of what's left in stock - about 450 of the 600 you started with.

It is true that

> when more is sold it will alter this calculation forever moving

If the goal is set week by week then in each week the goal is to sell half of what's still in stock. If no new new stock appears, then if the goal is met the unsold stock on hand halves each week and approaches $0$. If new stock appears the sales team has more work to do - they should always sell half of what's on hand.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my issue I can't wrap my head round is I am using units sold to determine the outstanding/unsold items that I need to get 51% and see if people have met this 51%, so if I was to then say lets see if they have met this, if someone then sells 1 more item, this just changes the original calculation, e.g. I am altering the very thing that I am using as a measure

Comment: That's not a contradiction. If you are driving somewhere 100 miles away then the distance you have to cover is constantly decreasing. So is the percentage of the distance still to cover.